# Unable to get data from mysql using jquery/ajax/json to select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am running a simple script to get data from mysql into select box but it doesn't fetch any data. below is the code :

```
<body>
Team :  <select id="teamname"> </select> <br />
Members : <select id="members"> </select>
</body>
```

Jquery :

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$.getJSON("ajax.php", function(data){
    $("#teamname").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function() {
        $("#teamname").append("<option>" + this('team_name') + "</option>");
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$result=array();
$getteams=mysql_query("select * from tbl_teams");
if(mysql_num_rows($getteams)){
    while($gotteams=mysql_fetch_array($getteams)){
        array_push($result,array('id' => $gotteams['team_id'],
                                 'name' => $gotteams['team_name']));
    }
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
}
```

I tried everymeans and every other example available online but still doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: Check for errors, check your console, check your logs.

Comment: Open firebug, see what is return in http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got column name as   'name' not 'team_name' in array ( `'name' => $gotteams['team_name']`)

try

```
$.each(data.result, function() {
        $("#teamname").append("<option>" + this['name'] + "</option>");
    });
```